How to design schemas
To preface, I'm an novice-intermediate Python user and am using ibis+duckdb, pandas, numpy right now.
I'm attempting to build a database for medical device results and raw data. To simplify things here, I've created a model of my current schemas in excel. In short, I will have two tables: T1 contains a single row per run with the result; T2 contains many rows of raw data per run. The results and raw data are linked by the runid. Should I keep T2 in longform (melted, first example) or transpose it (second example)? Or should I do something else entirely?
I imagine the second option will be easier to query since there are fewer rows. In either case, the runid will be indexed.
Thank you for the help and please let me know if anything is unclear. Also feel free to give any other advice you think I might need (I don't know what I don't know!).
See example images here: https://imgur.com/a/N6hO7y2
